# How to add title to column of the xts time series

Tags: r, csv, xts, zoo, quantmod

I want to download some stock details using quantmod and have successfully saved files using `write.csv`:

```
write.csv(df,file="AAPL.csv")
```

The problem is that there is no header for the date in the csv file.

```
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2014-10-01    100.59    100.69    98.70      99.18    51491300      97.09741
2014-10-02     99.27    100.22    98.04      99.90    47757800      97.80230
2014-10-03     99.44    100.21    99.04      99.62    43469600      97.52818
2014-10-06     99.95    100.65    99.42      99.62    37051200      97.52818
2014-10-07     99.43    100.12    98.73      98.75    42094200      96.67644
2014-10-08     98.76    101.11    98.31     100.80    57404700      98.68340
2014-10-09    101.54    102.38   100.61     101.02    77376500      98.89877
```

I want something like this

```
  Date      AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2014-10-01    100.59    100.69    98.70      99.18    51491300      97.09741
2014-10-02     99.27    100.22    98.04      99.90    47757800      97.80230
2014-10-03     99.44    100.21    99.04      99.62    43469600      97.52818
```

I tried this

```
colnames(df)[1] <- "Date"
```

but it changes title of `AAPL.Open` instead.

Comment: You cannot. The date column is not a column. It is row names.

Comment: More precisely, it is index attribute (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28532262/3710546).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Joshua Ulrich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28532262/3710546), "*`getSymbols` does not return a data.frame by default; it returns an `xts` object. `xts` objects do not have row names. They have an index attribute that you can access with the `index` function.*"

Then you need:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
row.names(AAPL)
# NULL
AAPL <- as.data.frame(AAPL)
AAPL$Date <- row.names(AAPL)
# Move last column to first position
# AAPL <- AAPL[,c(7, 1:6)]
cln <- ncol(AAPL) # 7
AAPL <- AAPL[, c(cln, 1:(cln-1))]
row.names(AAPL) <- NULL
head(AAPL)
#         Date AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 1 2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80   309579900      11.14677
# 2 2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66   211815100      11.39418
# 3 2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05   208685400      11.31304
# 4 2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47   199276700      11.36891
# 5 2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   837324600      12.31332
# 6 2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   738220000      12.90259
```

Comment: how this code can be implemented to a large number of columns(>10).  I have tried like this `cln<-ncol(AAPL)
AAPL <- AAPL[,c(cln+1, 1:cln)]` but its giving date as numbers

Comment: It is not correct. It should be `AAPL <- AAPL[, c(cln, 1:(cln-1))]`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `write.zoo` instead of `write.csv` to write the xts objects to csv files. Set `index.name = "Date"` if you want the index column header to be "Date" instead of "Index" (the default).

For example:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
write.zoo(AAPL, file="AAPL.csv", sep=",", index.name="Date")
readLines("AAPL.csv", n=3)
# [1] "\"Date\",\"AAPL.Open\",\"AAPL.High\",\"AAPL.Low\",\"AAPL.Close\",\"AAPL.Volume\",\"AAPL.Adjusted\""
# [2] "2007-01-03,86.289999,86.579999,81.899999,83.800002,309579900,11.146771"                            
# [3] "2007-01-04,84.050001,85.949998,83.820003,85.659998,211815100,11.394181"
```

You can then use `read.zoo` to read these types of files into zoo object (which you can convert to xts via `as.xts`).

I'd also suggest you use `saveRDS` or `save` to save the files in binary format, unless you absolutely must save them as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
df$Date <- row.names(df)
row.names(df) <- NULL
```